# Why do HECU soldiers put grenades on the ground?

Tags: half-life

In *Half-Life*, the HECU soldiers sometimes just bend down, put a grenade on the ground as if it was a landmine, and then (maybe) run away.

Why exactly are they doing this? As in, what's the tactic? Are they hoping you'll chase them and the grenade will go off just as you pass it?

It's very odd because, for one thing you're unlikely to be chasing the soldiers with your crowbar and instead be hiding behind cover trying to shoot them, but also sometimes they don't get away in time and just blow themselves up! Though the latter could be just down to a primitive or buggy A.I. it still seems like a strange tactic in the first place.